# How to implement contract testing when kafka is involved in microservice architecture?

Tags: java, jvm, apache-kafka, microservices, pact

I am currently working on a project where we have kafka implementation in micro service architecture. Were you successful in creating contract test cases for mS to kafka topic interaction please using pact-jvm ?

My implementation is microservice1 publishes a message to a REST Client which in turn posts the message to Kafka Topic. microservice2 uses GET method to retrieve messages from the Kafka Topic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pact-JVM supports Message Pacts, which encapsulate a message that is consumed (one way) over some mechanism, normally a message queue. The idea is to test the consumer code can consume the message via a consumer test, and then verify that the provider generates an appropriate message. The actual message queue is not used in the test.

[image: Contract over a message queue]

This was originally developed to apply contract tests for micro-services communicating over a Kafka message queue.

The tests are done in two parts, just like Request-Response Pact tests, except the Consumer reads the message during the consumer pact test and if successful a pact file is written. Then the provider code is called to generate a message, and that is compared to what is in the pact file.

[image]

The relevant sections of the Pact-JVM docs are:

- [Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-provider-gradle/README.md#verifying-a-message-provider-version-2212)
- [Maven Plugin](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-provider-maven/README.md#verifying-a-message-provider-version-2212)
- [JUnit Example](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-provider-junit/README.md#example-of-amqp-message-test)

Comment: Thanks @ronald-holshausen Can you also point to consumer JVM section where the contract is getting generated please ?

Comment: Sure, here is a link for a JUnit test: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit/README.md#consumer-test-for-a-message-consumer