# Pact with Spring Cloud Streams

Tags: pact

I want to adopt to PACT contract for micro-services.  I am using Spring Cloud  Stream and I want to integrate contract with Kafka. Is it possible to do so?

TIA.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884316/how-to-implement-contract-testing-when-kafka-is-involved-in-microservice-archite ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement contract testing when kafka is involved in microservice architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884316/how-to-implement-contract-testing-when-kafka-is-involved-in-microservice-archite)